# Flutter run stuck on white screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter issue I can't resolve. I tried all common things like `flutter clean`, restarting pc, wiping emulator data and few more things still getting stuck on white screen basically.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:55863/xq7cW6jF1O8=/ws    // this statement stays as its is
```

```
void main() => MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.black,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    );
```

Basically connection to VM is not happening.

### Edit

My dartDeveloperTool says unable to connect to vm service, but it opens in chrome and doesn't show any widget just clean dartDebugger tool.

Call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread).

Comment: does `flutter doctor` say anything?

Comment: no every thing is clear

Comment: Now i got it actually the issue is i created a project and then in the middle of it I upgraded flutter and even switched the branch to stable from developer. So this must be the issue hope no one will do this silly thing again.

Comment: have you got this fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Of course, it won't work.

Because you need to wrap it in `runApp` method. Like this:

```
void main() { 
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.black,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But it's kinda bad practice to put your `MaterialApp` inside your `main()` function. Try to move it into a `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`.

Here's the example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: null, // Change null with your own widgets
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. In my case culprit was corporate proxy.
I have fixed it by setting Environment variables (User variables section) as I was using Windows machine.

```
HTTP_PROXY to http://proxy-ip:port
HTTPS_PROXY to http://proxy-ip:port
NO_PROXY to localhost,127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I actually identified this to be my problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't underestimate the importance of **runApp()** - If you don't use it - your app (which is one big widget) will result in an indefinite white screen because it has no constraints...

According to the documentation it:

`/// Inflate the given widget and attach it to the screen. The widget is given constraints during layout that force it to fill the entire screen.`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, run app on `debug` mode working normal but I build file apk for `release` mode, app only show white screen. I finally found the solution. The problem was with my `grade` version. I downgrade version of grade in `android/build.grade` to `3.5.0`, it works normally again.

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just faced a similar issue today and removing the Dart/Flutter extensions and installing them back solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue of white screen with my friend project, the mistake was missing runApp() in Main.dart file, given below

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CircuitProvider>(
            create: (ctx) => CircuitProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
}
```

So then it was replaced like,

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CircuitProvider>(
            create: (ctx) => CircuitProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced with this problem in working app so in my case I've restarted phone and it was ok. Also check memory on your device maybe you have no free space